# S3 Notification Occurrence or SQS Reception Sequencer Ordering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

From the [Amazon S3 Event Notifications documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

> In your notification configuration you can request that Amazon S3 publish events to an SQS queue. Currently, Standard SQS queue is only allowed as an Amazon S3 event notification destination, whereas FIFO SQS queue is not allowed. For more information about SQS, see Amazon SQS product detail page.

Will the sequencer on an SQS event queue's object events reflect the order in which S3 operations occurred, or the order in which the SQS queue (non-fifo) received the events?

Comment: Since Standard SQS messages [have no order guarantee](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html#standard-queues-message-order) then the question is rather moot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *sequencer* found at `event.Records[0].s3.object.sequencer` is only intended to disambiguate event ordering for a single object key in a single bucket.

It allows you to determine the ordering of events impacting a single object, such as multiple overwrites of one object or creation of multiple versions of one object.

Across events for different buckets or objects within a bucket, the sequencer value should not be considered useful for ordering comparisons.

Instead, use `event.Records[0].eventTime` for comparing the ordering of events impacting different objects.

In fact, you can often just use this value, even for a single object, unless the events are close in time.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

Note that when comparing sequencer values for one object, you must first determine the maximum length of the longest sequencer value and left-pad all the others to the same length with `0` and then compare them lexically, as strings, not numbers (they are hex strings)... so if you have sequencer values `21` and `1f38` theb you need to pad the `21` to `0021` at which point it's correctly determined as being less than `1f37`.  These are examples, real sequencers are much longer.  Do not expect sequencers to be monotonic -- only that later values are always larger than earlier values, for one object.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation for Standard queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html):

> Standard queues provide best-effort ordering which ensures that messages are generally delivered in the same order as they're sent.

So order of events is not guaranteed, but will roughly reflect the order at which they are sent from S3.

Edit: You can use [SentTimestamp in the message attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) to see when the message was sent to the queue, and sort by that.

Comment: True, the queue won't necessarily deliver the events in order, but will the sequencer in the message contain the true ordering, allowing me to save the events, and sort them at a later date, after all events have been received?

Comment: Edited my answer to include this

Comment: Thank you for this answer, as it solves my problem. However, I chose the later answer as the solution because it tells me the _why_ as well as the solution, and corrects me on what the sequencer is for, which I had previously misunderstood.

Comment: If it solves your problem then this should be marked as the solution, but it's okay either way, glad your problem is solved

Comment: Only one answer can be marked as a solution. I choose the more relevant of two.